# SharePoint 2019 Security group AD group

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, active-directory, security, groups

There are few security groups in my SharePoint site .AD groups are added to the security groups. Is there any way using REST API to find out that the current user belongs to which all security groups .There is a check box present in a customised form which is accessible to specific security group members. So I want to extract the details of the current user.

Answer (score 1):

In sharepoint, AD group is treated as a normal user. There is such rest api to find out the user in which AD groups .

Comment: Is there any way using javascript to fetch  details of the current user to which security groups it belongs .I am able to fetch normal user that are directly added to security groups.